# Ipython error " No module named 'mayavi' "

Tags: python

i am trying to plot Spherical harmonics in Jupyiter Notebook. For this reason i want to use mylab from mayjavi and I get always the same error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6ab9ae7ba180> in <module>()
----> 1 from mayavi import mlab
  2 import numpy as np
  3 from scipy.special import sph_harm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mayavi'
```

Have someone an idea, how i can fix that?

Comment: Install `mayavi`.

Comment: I mean (first google search): https://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/pythonquestions/141618-ModuleNotFoundError-No-module-named-mayavi.html

Answer (score 0):

in command line "pip install mayavi"

Comment: have you ever workwled with pip? if not it is a very good opretunity to start, it is one of the best fearltures in python, try to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

if your not using anaconda :

```
pip install mayavi
```

if your using anaconda first you need to check whether your system default python is the same as your anaconda ipython kernel if its the same last command will do the job if not , you have to `cd` in to the `bin` folder in your anaconda directory and use this command :

```
./pip install mayavi
```

or maybe this will work :

```
conda install mayavi
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer. The first comment pip install mayavi does not work,  i am getting an error. I dont really know how to work with the command line. Could u give me an example of the cd command, so that i can switch in the bin folder (btw I use Windows 7 pro).

Comment: @Miradius I'm not sure about windows but I Think it should be like this : open your command prompt ,1 . C: , 2. cd anaconda(or what ever your anaconda folder name is ), 3.cd bin , 4. try this pip install mayavi , and see it wroks or not